# python How do you sort list by occurrence with out removing elements from the list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, frequency

Just wondering how do you sort a list by frequency/occurrence   in python 2.7 and if 2 elements occur the same number of times then the element that appears first in the original list is places ahead of the other element in the new list.

For example:

```
list = [5,6,8,9,8,8,3,4,4,6,6]
sorted_list = [6,6,6,8,8,8,4,4,5,9,3]
```

Any idea why the solution doesn't work for [1,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1].The output is [3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1] but the correct output is [1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2]
Thanks again

Comment: I just posted an answer but I'm wondering why in your expected output the `8` is before the `6` even though `6` occured first in the original list?

Comment: Sorry I messed up the desired output I changed it now thanks

Comment: MSeifert's (& my) code gives the correct answer for `[1,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1]`, and I assume Mureinik's updated version does too, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Counter` class from `collections` as sorting key. Since you may have multiple elements with the same number of occurrences, you can use the value itself as a secondary sorting key so that identical elements are grouped together:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = [5,6,8,9,8,8,3,4,4,6,6] 
>>> c = Counter(lst)
>>> sorted(lst, key = lambda x : (c[x], x), reverse = True)
[8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 9, 5, 3]
```

EDIT:
As MSeifert commented, ties should be broken by the order of first appearance, not the value of the element. This can be done using the `index` function on the original list:

```
>>> sorted(lst, key = lambda x : (-1 * c[x], lst.index(x)))
[6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 3]
```

Comment: secondary sorting key always has a special place in my heart

Comment: that said, I think you forgot to define `c`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yup - had a couple of tries till I got it right, and tried to only copy-paste the relevant lines. Obviously, I forgot one :-) Edited and fixed, thanks for noticing!

Comment: However the question wanted that items with the same number of occurences appear in the "order of first appearance", not by their "value". Note the `5,9,3` in the expected output vs. `9, 5, 3` in yours.

Comment: @MSeifert hmm, good point! I completely missed that. Edited my answer to add a solution for that condition too.

Comment: However, the new version is O(n²), due to indexing each list item.

Answer (score 2):

To do this kind of sorting you need to find the first indices and the counts of each item. I'll use one function to do both but there are also other approaches:

```
def count_and_first_index(it):
    dct_counts = {}
    dct_first = {}
    for idx, item in enumerate(it):
        if item in dct_counts:
            dct_counts[item] += 1
        else:
            dct_counts[item] = 1
            dct_first[item] = idx

    return dct_counts, dct_first
```

Then sorting is simple using a `key`-argument:

```
>>> lst = [5,6,8,9,8,8,3,4,4,6,6]

>>> counts, firstidx = count_and_first_index(lst)

>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (counts[x], -firstidx[x]), reverse=True)
[6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 3]
```

I negated the `index` because it sorts reversed and you wanted the first item first. However you could also negate `counts` and remove `reverse`:

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (-counts[x], firstidx[x]))
[6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 3]
```

Comment: I guess you could also do `sorted(lst, key=lambda x:(-lst.count(x), lst.index(x)))`, although that's rather inefficient in the way that it does the counting and indexing (O(n^2) instead of O(n)).

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, that's why I wrote "I'll use one function to do both but there are also other approaches". I felt it would spoil me to use an `O(n**2)` approach (it also traverses the list twice because `count` and `index` are seperate operations!) when a `O(n)` approach is (short and) possible.

Comment: Well, 2O(n²) is still O(n²) :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah, but that doesn't make me feel any better. However I would suggest that you also post your suggestion as another answer. It's really short (code-wise) and for really short iterables the `count` and `index` are pretty fast. Some people like that :)

Comment: I guess I _could_ post a separate answer, but it'd mostly be an explanation of why you shouldn't do it that way unless the list is really small due to the O(n²) issue, and that they should really use your solution instead. :)